# Iterations Error with location.path()

Tags: angularjs

I got the following Error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["isActive('/production'); newVal: [\"/production\"]; oldVal: [\"/production\"]"],["isActive('/production'); newVal: [\"/production\"]; oldVal: [\"/production\"]"],["isActive('/production'); newVal: [\"/production\"]; oldVal: [\"/production\"]"],["isActive('/production'); newVal: [\"/production\"]; oldVal: [\"/production\"]"],["isActive('/production'); newVal: [\"/production\"]; oldVal: [\"/production\"]"]]
```

When I use this directive:

```
function mainMenu ($location) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/directives/mainMenu',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        return $location.path().match(viewLocation)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML (Jade)

```
ul.nav.nav-pills(role="tablist")
    li(ng-class="{active: isActive('/production')}")
        a(ui-sref="production") Produktion
    li(ng-class="{active: isActive('/market')}")
        a(ui-sref="market") Markt

ul.nav.nav-tabs(role="tablist" ng-if="isActive('/production')")
    li(ng-class="{active: isActive('/production/board')}")
        a(ui-sref="production.board") Plantafel
    li(ng-class="{active: isActive('/production/warehouse')}")
        a(ui-sref="production.warehouse") Lager
```

Any Ideas why? I use ui-router, with nested views, thats the reason for using the match() expression!

Thank you!

**Edit:**

```
ul.nav.nav-pills(role="tablist")
    li(ng-class="{active:$state.includes('production')}")
        a(ui-sref="production") Produktion
```

This didn't work for me :( I need it because I will the active class on production, when for example the nested view production.board is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For angular ui-router you can use `$state.includes`

```
function mainMenu ($state) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/directives/mainMenu',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        return $state.includes(viewLocation);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And also there is standart directive [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active), and take a look at [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

**EDIT 1:**

You should pass state name (`production.board`) not the state url (`/production/board`)

**EDIT 2:**

You can not access to `$state` from view, because it takes it from `$scope`, define `$scope.$state = $state` in controller.

But it is not the proper way, it makes your code dirty.

It's better to use function:

In view: `ng-class="isActive('production.board')"`

In controller: `return $state.includes(viewLocation) ? 'active' : ''`;

Comment: Thank you! Try to get it work with my nested view! please see my first post!

Comment: @nofear87 this might be helpful